# Laravel project only works when main root = project public folder

Tags: laravel, windows, nginx

Hello I am trying to serve a laravel project with nginx where the project is located in:

```
C:/nginx/html/project_folder
```

This config works 100% when I go to localhost in the browser or the servername. Main page and all routes work correctly.  Problem with this approach is the url is simply localhost and I can only work with one project at a time.

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         C:/nginx/html/project_folder/public;

        location / {
            # root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
           # root           html;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I try to do something like below, I can no longer reach the laravel project by going to localhost/project_name, localhost/project_name/index.php works but is unstyled and all routes return "no input file specified" and simply localhost returns the nginx splash page.

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         C:/nginx/html;

        location / {
            # root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
        
        location /project_name/public {
            root        C:/nginx/html/project_name/public;
            index       index.php;
            try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
           # root           html;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

I've been searching for hours on here and can't figure out why this is happening and how I can resolve it.

Comment: remember to update `APP_URL` to be `http://localhost/project_name`

Comment: I updated my APP_URL in the .env to that as well as /public and both result in the same "no input file specified"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing 2 things:

1. Nested the php location block inside of the /project_name/public location block
2. Updated the try files from `/index.php?$query_string;` to `/project_name/public/index.php?$query_string;`

Final working config. Both localhost and localhost/project_name/public along with all routes are now working.

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         C:/nginx/html;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    
    location /project_name {
        alias       C:/nginx/html/project_name/public;
        index       index.php;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ @project_name;
        
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }           
    }

    location @project_name {
        rewrite /project_name/(.*)$ /project_name/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this is not a solution, you have not to specify `public`, `public` should be document root, not a path to the page...

Comment: If it is your solution, good for you, it is an edge case, 99% of people will never achieve it using `public` on the path, if it works for you, excellent, hope we were able to help you, just remember to add `/public` on the `APP_ENV` because the framework assumes it has NOT to add `public` in any URL, that is the issue

Comment: I posted what I initially tried and you say 99% will never achieve it the way which works for me yet will not post a helpful answer? I understand this is probably something very simple which I am overlooking but I am willing to learn if someone could point me in the right direction! None of your suggestions have been helpful thus far..

Comment: @matiaslauriti I just realized I had the incorrect "working" config posted in the answer. If it is still not the correct way of doing this please point me in the right direction so I can research.